# passing a self function as a callback using closure/function binding

Tags: javascript, function, binding, closures

Is it possible to use closure or function binding to pass a self function as an argument for callback from within the function itself?

I used some code to better explain what I'm trying to achieve.

```
x: function(a, b, c){
 if(certain conditions not met){
   y(pass function x as argument along with arguments a,b,c for callback);
 }
 //blah blah
}
y: function(callbackFunc){
 //do some stuff
 //then execute callback function
 callbackFunc();
}
```

Comment: you can't actually pass a function *with* parameters, but you can pass the function along with an array of parameters

Comment: @Jeremy Oh cool! I think that could work! But how do you reference the function itself from inside of it? Can you give me a short example

Comment: what's wrong with calling it `this.x`?

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/yxap11m6/

Answer (score 1):

You can define `x` as a named function, set a flag at `if` condition to determine whether to pass `x` or call `x` to prevent recursive calls to `y` and `x`; use `Function.prototype.bind()` to set `this` to current or other object, alternate flag at `y`, call `x` with `y` to access original parameters passed to `x`; optionally pass additional parameters to `x`.

```js
var obj = {
  z: true,
  x: function x(a, b, c) {
    if (this.z === true) {
      this.y(x.bind(this, arguments));
    } else {
      console.log(arguments, this)
    }
    //blah blah
  },
  y: function(callbackFunc) {
    //do some stuff
    //then execute callback function
    if (this.z) {
      this.z = false;
      // pass additional parameters to `x`
      callbackFunc("abc")
    };
  }
}

obj.x(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 x: function(a, b, c){
     if(certain conditions not met){
       this.y(this.x, a,b,c);
     }
     //blah blah
    }
    y: function(callbackFunc,a1,b1,c1){
     //do some stuff
     //then execute callback function
     callbackFunc(a1,b1,c1);
    }
```

I have written a1,b1,c1 just to differenciate, you can use a,b,c